# A proof that two subfields of the same finite field equal if they have the same size

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose $K$ is a finite field and $F_1$, $F_2$ are subfields of $K$ having the same number of elements. Then $F_1 = F_2$.

I have seen several posts on MSE about this fact (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795817/are-two-subfields-of-the-same-finite-field-equal-if-they-have-the-same-size) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/if-e-and-f-are-subfields-of-a-finite-field-k-and-e-cong-f-prove-that-e?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and their answers all use the polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ to prove the fact. But it seems to me that one could prove the fact by considering merely the multiplicative group of these fields: since $K^*$ is cyclic, it contains only one subgroup of each order $d \mid |K^*|$, hence $F^*_1$ and $F^*_2$ coincide, so are $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Is there anything wrong with the latter proof? Why does the standard proof refer to  $X^{p^n}-X$?

Comment: Looks like it's correct. However, the statement is true even without the assumption that $K$ is finite. If $K$ is any field, then for any natural number $q$, $K$ contains at most one subfield with $q$ elements. If $K$ is not finite, its multiplicative group is not cyclic, so the same argument will not work. But the proof with the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x$ still works without change.

Comment: @Mark it could still be made to work by using that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic

Comment: @doetoe But how does it help? A group can contain many different cyclic subgroups of the same order. It's just that a group which is itself finite cyclic contains at most one cyclic subgroup of each finite order, which is what OP used.

Comment: @Mark $F_1^\ast$ and $F_2^\ast$ generate a finite subgroup $H$ of $K^\ast$, and $H$ is therefore cyclic itself. Since $F_1^\ast$ and $F_2^\ast$ are subgroups of it of the same order, they have to be equal.